# ¿Como puedo desplegar los datos de mi tabla mysql en una List text de TKinter en Python 2.7?

Tags: mysql, python, base-de-datos, python-2.7, tkinter

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una interfaz grafica para mi base de datos MySQL con TKinter de Python 2.7. Estuve checando la documentacion de tkinter asi como otras fuentes pero no logro hacer que los registros de mi tabla se desplieguen dentro de la list box en lugar de en el Shell de python. Soy nuevo con TKinter. Que como le puedo hacer?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
from Tkinter import *
import MySQLdb



#ventana

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Erick Finn,s Reporter")
var = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()

def fun1():
fun1 = str(usuario_text.get())
return var.set(fun1)

 def mostrar():

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec",            db = "efrias002")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM base17")
data = cursor.fetchall()
print " ", sorted (data)
conn.close()
return var2.set(mostrar)


l1=Label(ventana, text = "Usuario")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2=Label(ventana,text = "Numero de Ticket")
l2.grid(row=2,column=0)

l2=Label(ventana,text = "Aplicacion")
l2.grid(row=4,column=0)

l2=Label(ventana,text = "Problema")
l2.grid(row=6,column=0)


#campos de entrada

usuario_text=StringVar()
e1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=usuario_text)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

ticket_text=StringVar()
e2=Entry(ventana,textvariable=ticket_text)
e2.grid(row=2,column=1)

aplicacion_text=StringVar()
e3=Entry(ventana,textvariable=aplicacion_text)
e3.grid(row=3,column=1)

problema_text=StringVar()
e4=Entry(ventana,textvariable=problema_text)
e4.grid(row=4,column=1, rowspan=2)

#definir listbox

list1 = Listbox(ventana,listvariable = var2,height=6, width=35)
list1.grid(row=30, column=10, columnspan=3)

#crear scroll

sb1=Scrollbar(ventana)
sb1.grid(row=30,column=14)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

#crear botones

b1=Button(ventana, text="Buscar" ,command=fun1)
b1.pack()
b1.grid(row=31 ,column=10)

b2 = Button(ventana, text="Mostrar", command=mostrar)
b2.pack()
b2.grid(row=31, column=11)




ventana.mainloop()
```

Asi mismo al darle al boton "Mostrar", despliega loa datos de la tabla en el shell de python y en la list box solo despliega:

```
(Function "Mostrar" at 0x02A6E970>)
```

Comment: ¿Que campos tiene tu tabla?

Comment: Los campos que tengo son 7: ID, Fecha, Usuario, Aplicacion, Folio_Ticket, Status e Inputway

Comment: Y cual de esos campos desea mostrar?

Comment: Todos. Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es crear la interfaz grafica para que yo ingrese los datos y al darle por ejemplo al boton "Agregar" haga el query Insert y cuando le de al boton "Mostrar" te muestre en la list box la informacion contenida en la tabla. Pues actualmente tengo que ejecutar el script de python en el shell.